# MYSQL Select row when first part of condition is valid (with a group by)

Tags: mysql, sql

I really don't know how to find an answer for my question, so I'm asking you.

Here is the table I have :

```
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
| id | start_date |  end_date  |  id_person  |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
| 1  | 2017-10-01 | 2017-12-01 |      1      |
| 2  | 2017-07-01 | 2017-09-01 |      1      |
| 3  | 2016-01-01 | 2016-02-01 |      1      |
| 4  | 2016-05-01 | 2016-06-01 |      2      |
| 5  | 2016-01-01 | 2016-02-01 |      2      |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
```

And here is the query I tried to use :

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ((start_date < NOW() AND end_date > NOW())
OR start_date > NOW()
OR end_date < NOW())
GROUP BY `id_person`
```

The result I was expecting was this one :

```
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
| id | start_date |  end_date  |  id_person  |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
| 2  | 2017-07-01 | 2017-09-01 |      1      | // matches first condition
| 4  | 2016-05-01 | 2016-06-01 |      2      | // matches 3rd condition and has the most recent start_date
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
```

If you didn't get what I did wrong yet, I'm going to tell you.

Here, I was trying to show a single row per person but I wanted this row to match the first condition it finds and not the others, I don't want the row to just be ordered by start_date. It is like a custom order where I want the first row for each person.

The problem is that this query doesn't work since the GROUP BY statement doesn't apply conditions first. (even if it did, I'm not sure the condition would only select one row)

I really don't know how I can achieve that and I don't even know if it is possible, I hope someone can lead me towards any solution.

Thanks for reading this, I'll answer as fast as I can to give you more informations.

Comment: You can ignore the dates comparison entirely.

Comment: WHERE conditions are always applied before GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea...

```
SELECT m.*
  FROM my_table m
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.id_person
            , MAX(x.start_date) start_date
         FROM my_table x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT id_person
                   , MIN(CASE WHEN NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN 'A' WHEN start_date > NOW() THEN 'B' WHEN end_date < NOW() THEN 'C' END) rule 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY id_person
            ) y
           ON y.id_person = x.id_person
          AND y.rule = CASE WHEN NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN 'A' WHEN start_date > NOW() THEN 'B' WHEN end_date < NOW() THEN 'C' END
        GROUP
           BY id_person
     ) n
    ON n.id_person = m.id_person
   AND n.start_date = m.start_date;

+----+------------+------------+-----------+
| id | start_date | end_date   | id_person |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+
|  2 | 2017-07-01 | 2017-09-01 |         1 |
|  4 | 2016-05-01 | 2016-06-01 |         2 |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Yes I guess I didn't explain myself clearly enough, I get what you're telling me here and that is my problem, I want the query to match the FIRST rule it encounters so in your table, it would be rule line 2 (rule A) and line 4 (rule C)

The thing is I don't know how to do it... My query might be wrong at many points.

Comment: This is working perfectly, but I'm still wondering something about the inner JOIN statement, may I remove the 2nd CASE you wrote ? Since "y" table does return only one row per person I guess I can remove it right ? I tried the query without it and it also works, just asking you to be sure.

Comment: @A.Natoli No, I don't think you can. I'm sure that there are other (and possibly simpler) ways of writing this, but I don't think you can simply exclude that line.

Comment: Are we talking about line 15 ?

Comment: @A.Natoli Yes. I don't think you can exclude any line from query. I'm really not a fan of the 'undocumented hack' solution provided by your other correspondent.

Comment: @Strawberry. Absolutely. I wouldn't recommend The SELECT * FROM GROUP BY hack in production code. It could be a handy way of confirming if the algorithmic approach of looking at the direction and distance to end date is correct.

Comment: @A. Natoli. The group by gives the highest priority rule, which is joined to the *matching* rows in the table, so the CASE is needed in both places as it is the same calculation (the rule that applies to the row). I think the next mysql release will have common table expressions, which you could use to avoid repeating expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If are happy to write the rules directly in sql rather than as where conditions you can ask the database for what yuo want more directly.

This means taking a step back to see what the rules you want are. It looks like you want to prioritise the entries by closest date, showing first current, then future, then historical. It also looks like end_date >= start_date, which means you only need to look at end_date to find what you are looking for.

Mysql can answer the question abusing it's group by functionality (until recent versions).

```
SELECT t.* FROM 
(
   SELECT t.* 
   FROM table t
   ORDER BY SIGN(t.end_date - NOW()),ABS(t.end_date-NOW())
)
GROUP BY t.id_person
```

A standard sql method that will also play better with indexes would be to look for end dates before and after today separately.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
JOIN (
    SELECT t.person_id
      ,COALESCE(first_not_ended.end_date,t.last_ended.end_date) AS end_date
    FROM table t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT t.*,MIN(end_date) AS end_date
        FROM table t
        WHERE t.end_date > NOW()
        GROUP by t.person_id
    ) first_not_ended
    ON t.person_id=first_not_ended.person_id
    AND t.end_date=first_not_ended.end_ate
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT t.person_id,MAX(end_date) AS end_date
        FROM table t
        WHERE t.end_date < NOW()
        GROUP by t.person_id
    ) last_ended
    ON t.person_id=last_ended.person_id
    AND t.end_date=last_ended.end_date        
) closest
ON t.person_id=closest.person_id
AND t.end_date=closest.end_date
```

Comment: I really like how you found another way to resolve this problem, this is really smart. But I have a problem with the "closest" SELECT which gives me many identical rows I don't know why, Inner selects work great.

Comment: I've edited the join to fix that. I had intended to use a left join from table to first_not_ended and last_ended, because an outer join between first_not_ended and last_ended might perform poorly depending on how the optimiser looks at it.

Comment: N.B. The example data doesn't show what you want to happen when start_date > Now() as the rule doesn't apply for either id_person 1 or 2. This approach looks for the closest as opposed to the latest entry of the highest matching rule. If what you want is the latest date, you should follow the approach taken by @Strawberry. Or add a third left join.